# Talend tRestClient missing xml tags: specific tag not returning in response

Tags: xml, rest, talend

When I test in Postman using the method "Get" and "basic Auth" and acept "XML", the response comes OK(complete), like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<category code="cine" pk="87967484" uri="h...">
<comments/>
<creationtime>2017-08-18T14:54:33.640-03:00</creationtime>
<modifiedtime>2017-10-05T16:40:00.552-03:00</modifiedtime>
<allSubcategories/>    
<categories/>
<categoryFeatureComponents/>
<conteudos/>
<data_sheet/>
<description>&lt;p&gt;Troque seus pontos....&amp;nbsp; 00&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;2 Ingressos para sess&amp;otilde;es 2D&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;2 Ingressos para sess&amp;otilde;es 3D&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
</description>
<detail/>
<linkComponents/>
<logo/>
<medias/>
<name>Cine</name>
<normal/>
<ofertaTipo>COMUM</ofertaTipo>
<others/>     
<thumbnails/>
</category>
```

But when I use tRestClient or TRest configured as the same in postman, the response from tXmlMap returns null for the "Description" and the "Name" tags, unlike other tags (ex.: 'ofertaTipo') that return correctly.
I tried reading tFileInputXML with the result of postman saved in a file and that works fine.

Comment: I noticed description and name are lowercase in your example, could it be that your tag names aren't exactly as in your file ? Also, could you print what's returned by tRestClient using a tLogRow (tRestClient --main-- tLogRow)

Comment: I installed pentaho and tested and it worked correctly. But in talend, tRestClient --response-- tLogRow, it does not work, such tags do not return.                                                                                
        statusCode body string
[tLogRow_10] 200||<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<category code="cine" pk="87" uri="h..">
...
   <conteudos />
   <data_sheet />
   <detail />
   <linkComponents />
   <logo />
   <medias />
   <normal />
...

1246 milliseconds
[statistics] disconnected

Comment: I'm using TOS_DI-20160510_1709-V6.2.0 and TOS_BD-20170623_1246-V6.4.1

Comment: Solved! Just added "Accept-Language" = "pt" in tRest's Headers. Thank you all!